# Best Glide with Flaps T/O in DA20-A1

Tags: aircraft-performance, general-aviation

The Diamond Katana DA20-A1 Manual says that the best glide angle can be achieved with flaps in the t/o position at 72kn at maximum weight.

My naive understanding would be that a flaps up position would always provide a better glide angle, because of the lower drag. So why does the Katana apparently have a better glide with flaps t/o?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best glide flap setting is a matter of definition. If the base airfoil was optimized for high lift (like, say, the [Wortmann FX63-137](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=fx63137-il)), the cruise flap setting would be some trailing-edge up position. If that is defined as 0°, and the take-off setting is the one for which the airfoil has originally been optimized, then it should not be too surprising that it allows the best L/D.

A high zero-lift drag coefficient, like from a fixed landing gear, will drive the optimum L/D to low speeds and a high lift coefficient. That is where the Wortmann FX63-137 excels and the reason why the optimum L/D of the Katana is at such a low speed. The Katana has inherited this airfoil from the [H36 Dimona motorglider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_HK36_Super_Dimona), and here it had been selected to meet the minimum sink speed requirement at that time for certification as a motorglider.

Airfoil trivia: The Wortmann FX63-137 has originally been designed for a [human powered aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMPAC_Puffin) project. This explains its very high maximum lift at low Reynolds numbers.

Comment: Very detailed answer, thank you!