# How is NASA going to get high fuel economy on the X-57?

Tags: general-aviation, drag, experimental-aircraft, nasa

[This X-plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_X-57_Maxwell) is meant to fly soon.
[image]
It's a modified Tecnam.
The propeller direct wash over the wings, increasing lift. This allows the use of a smaller, high-aspect ratio, low drag wing.
But this isn't quite clear to me. Here's what I know about this.

- Light aircraft have oversized wings for cruise, needed due to a mandatory [minimum 61 knots](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/78395/45534) stall speed, and the lack of cabin pressurization generally prevents them flying high enough to make good use of the extra wing area at higher cruise speeds.
- The propwash from the Maxwell would act like a blown flap at low speeds, achieving the above requirement without a large wing but presumably sufficient redundancy to not matter.
- At cruise however, the propwash would increase friction drag by causing faster airflow over the wings, and possibly interfering with any laminar flow.
- The giant propellers at the tips are somehow meant to reduce induced drag - but how?
- This is a glorified blown flap.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** I just discovered/remembered that at cruise the inner propellers fold to reduce drag. But the point remains: what is so special about this glorified blown flap?

Comment: Besides that it has electric propulsion?

Comment: @zymhan Yes yes thank you. I think it does. OK, dupe this.